# Preventing curly braces from showing on webpage

Tags: angularjs

A simple program to help familiarize myself with AngularJS, and currently having an issue with the code within the  tags. Every time I run this code, the curly braces and the content inside always appear on the webpage, how do i prevent that from happening

```
<head>
    <title> Your Shopping Cart </title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="CartController">
<h1> Your Order </h1>

<div ng-repeat="item in items">

<input ng-model="item.quantity">
    *<span>{{item.title}}</span> //Keeps showing on webpage
    <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span> //Keeps showing on webpage
    <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>* //Keeps showing on webpage
<button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>

</div>

<script src="angular.min.js"> </script>

<script>
function CartController($scope) {$scope.items = [

    {title: 'Paint Pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
    {title: 'Polka Dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
    {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
    ];

    scope.remove = function(index){$scope.items.splice(iindex, 1);
    }
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Check the console for compile errors. Angular is probably crashing because of a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Move your angular library reference to head tag or the top of the body tag

```
<head>
    <title> Your Shopping Cart </title>
<script src="angular.min.js"> </script>
</head>
```

or

```
<body>
<script src="angular.min.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-bind or ng-cloak:

`ng-bind`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

```
*<span ng-bind="item.title"></span>
<span ng-bind="item.price | currency"></span>
<span ng-bind="item.price * item.quantity | currency"></span>*
```

`ng-cloak`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-cloak>
    <input ng-model="item.quantity">
    *<span>{{item.title}}</span> //Keeps showing on webpage
    <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span> //Keeps showing on webpage
    <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>* //Keeps showing on webpage
    <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Working Fiddle with `ng-bind` implemented : http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9154/

Comment: I used ng-bind, I only see the textbook and the heading. Nothing else is being displayed

Comment: @Robbie - please check the fiddle, it's working fine, also check the browser developer console if any error is there